# T-SQL : Join Tables Using 'Like'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `[TableA]` that looks like this:

```
ID     Name
---------------------------------------------
1      KENALOG 40 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION
2      KENALOG 10 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION
3      KENALOG 40 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION
4      KENALOG 40 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION
```

I have a second table `[TableB]` that contains this data:

```
Name                      Code
-------------------------------
Kenalog 40 MG/ML Inj      J3340
Kenalog 10 MG/ML Inj      J3310
```

I want the 4 rows in TableA to have the appropriate code from Table B like this:

```
ID     Name                                     Code
------------------------------------------------------
1      KENALOG 40 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    J3340
2      KENALOG 10 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    J3310
3      KENALOG 40 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    J3340
4      KENALOG 40 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    J3340
```

When I try this SQL:

```
Select 
    a.ID, a.Name, b.Code
From
    TableA a
Left Join 
    TableB b On a.Name Like '%' + Upper(b.Name) + '%'
```

I get:

```
ID     Name                                     Code
------------------------------------------------------
1      KENALOG 40 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    NULL
2      KENALOG 10 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    J3310
3      KENALOG 10 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    NULL
4      KENALOG 10 MG/ML INJECTION SUSPENSION    NULL
```

I have also tried a Left Outer Join [same result] and an Inner Join [returns only one row the one with Kenalog 10 MG ...] - and I have tried using CharIndex & SubString in the Join statement.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Does table b have any hidden white space in the name? You can check using datalength(), or change your join consdition `LIKE UPPER(TRIM(b.Name)) +’%'`

Comment: Can't reproduce: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fe01/1). You have a data problem, as @PrebenHuybrechts suggests.

Comment: @Preben Huybrechts. Thanks. There are no hidden spaces in the Name. I tried using the Trim(). Appreciate it!

Comment: @Eric Brandt: Thanks. Any suggestions about how I can resolve the data problem ... or even see it?

Comment: How about this? `Left Join TableB b On SUBSTRING(a.Name, 1, 16) = SUBSTRING(Upper(b.Name), 1, 16)`

Comment: `TRIM` isn't going to do you any good here without knowing what you're up against. It natively removes spaces, or ASCII character 32. You likely have an embedded non-printing character. There's a little loop on the BOL page for the [CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function that should get you started.

Comment: I am truly sorry, folks. The problem was with my eyes. The data example for TableB was incorrect - and therein lay the problem. In reality, this: Kenalog 40 MG/ML Inj ... was actually 'Kenalog 40MG/ML Inj' [no space between the 40 and the MG]. That's why there couldn't be a match. Again, sorry for the mistake - and thanks so much for your help.